# How do I include the XSL template parameter in the select statement?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Here is the XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="LAC">
    <table class="tableLAC">
      <tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="SectionHeading">
          <xsl:with-param name="strSection">LAC</xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="iSpanColumns">3</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SectionHeading">
    <xsl:param name="strSection"/>
    <xsl:param name="iSpanColumns"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell{$strSection}" colspan="{$iSpanColumns}">
        <div class="text{$strSection}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('//Labels/', {$strSection})"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have stripped everything out to convey the issue in hand. The **SectionHeading** template is not working right for this bit:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('//Labels/', {$strSection})"/>
```

In fact, it tells me that { is an unexpected token. I can't seem to get this right. I am trying to acheive this (if I were to write it manually):

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/LAC"/>
```

Thank you for your help.

**Update:**

I modified it to this:

```
  <xsl:template name="SectionHeading">
    <xsl:param name="strSection"/>
    <xsl:param name="iSpanColumns"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell{$strSection}" colspan="{$iSpanColumns}">
        <div class="text{$strSection}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('//Labels/',$strSection)"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

But now I only get "//Labels/LAC" as actual text in my output.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="WEEK-S-140.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
  <Labels>
    <TFGW>TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</TFGW>
    <AYFM>APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</AYFM>
    <LAC>LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</LAC>
  </Labels>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

XML has been cut down.

**Update:**

Confused. This also does not work:

```
  <xsl:template name="SectionHeading">
    <xsl:param name="strSection"/>
    <xsl:param name="iSpanColumns"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell{$strSection}" colspan="{$iSpanColumns}">
        <div class="text{$strSection}">
          <xsl:variable name="strPath">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('//Labels/',$strSection)"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="$strPath"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

But if I override:

```
  <xsl:template name="SectionHeading">
    <xsl:param name="strSection"/>
    <xsl:param name="iSpanColumns"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell{$strSection}" colspan="{$iSpanColumns}">
        <div class="text{$strSection}">
          <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/LAC"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

That latter one works. So this works too:

```
  <xsl:template name="SectionHeading">
    <xsl:param name="strSection"/>
    <xsl:param name="iSpanColumns"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell{$strSection}" colspan="{$iSpanColumns}">
        <div class="text{$strSection}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$strSection='TFGW'">
              <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/TFGW"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$strSection='AYFM'">
              <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/AYFM"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$strSection='LAC'">
              <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/LAC"/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

But it defeats the object of using a template method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until XSLT 3.0 there is no way of evaluating dynamically created XPath expressions (XSLT 3.0 gets `xsl:evaluate`).

But in this particular case the following, static XPath expression would work:

```
<div class="text{$strSection}">
  <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/*[name() = $strSection]"/>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, double-check that `//Labels` is actually what you want. A relative expression might be the smarter choice here.

Comment: No, this is a root node where I have the labels that will be repeated several times. I do it this way as I support over 30 languages, so it keeps one generic template where I dynamically replace the labels with the translated text when I create it. Otherwise, I have to replicate the label value each time within the xml nodes as opposed to just once.

Comment: I was referring to the `//`, which searches everywhere in the document and potentially returns unwanted nodes. If that can't happen for your data you're fine.

Comment: Ah, it always appears at the top of my file. The one and only <Labels> section.